# Confused about "respond_to?" method

Tags: ruby

Edit:  I'm using Ruby version 2.0.0

I have the following code in a file example.rb

```
def say_hello
  puts 'hi'
end

puts respond_to?(:say_hello)
say_hello
```

When running this code, the output is:

```
false
hi
```

I'm confused why false is returned for "respond_to?" when I can use that method.

The "respond_to?" method seems to work this way though:

```
class Person
  def say_bye
    puts 'bye'
  end
end

mike = Person.new
puts mike.respond_to?(:say_bye)
mike.say_bye
```

The output is:

```
true
bye
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why "respond_to?" returns false in the first case?

Comment: Interesting, I just ran it in irb and it worked for me. Have you tried to be more explicit by calling it on self perhaps? `puts self.respond_to?(:say_hello)`

Comment: self.respond_to(:say_hello) returns false.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running?

Comment: If I define the following:  def self.say_hello; puts 'hi'; end; puts respond_to(:say_hello);   That returns true.  I must be getting confused whether the methods need to be defined as class methods or instance methods.  It's interesting that my first example return true for you though... I'm using Ruby 2.0.0, that may be why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Top-level methods are defined as private, and `Object#respond_to?` ignores private methods by default (you need to pass second argument for it to recognize `say_hello`):

```
def say_hello
  puts 'hi'
end

puts respond_to?(:say_hello)                    #=> false
puts respond_to?(:say_hello, :include_private)  #=> true
say_hello
```

Comment: Not really. In Ruby 1.9.3 top level methods are defined as public.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up!  I ran "puts private_methods.sort" and sure enough, say_hello showed up as a private method.

Comment: @Jeffrey: From the question comments: "I'm using Ruby 2.0.0"

Comment: @Jeffrey I just tried 1.9.3 - top level methods are private, just like in 2.0.0

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby **.respond_to?**  A check method for Ruby, not Rails which has **respond_to**
 Takes a symbol and returns **true** if an object can receive that method, **else** it returns a **false**

Your first code has a missing dot(**.**) before respond_to? ... when I ran it printed ***hi*** but had no confirmation of true condition.

Syntax: object.respond_to?(:method)

-->  **[1,2,3,5,8,13].respond_to?(:push)**

Answer (score 3):

This one took a lot of digging.

As explained here, http://marakana.com/bookshelf/ruby_tutorial/scope.html near the bottom: "methods defined outside any class or module become private methods on Object and are available everywhere."

self, at top-level in a file, is a special thing called 'main'.

Now here's the funny part. Objects deny that they respond to private methods.

... the other answer has the rest of the info.

Comment: I would say it is correct that the objects deny that they respond to the private methods, as by default `respond_to?` only considers public methods, as discussed in other answers.