# Ruby's `respond_to?` do not work just after definition?

Tags: ruby

I have a module that defines a method if it is not already defined. This is the case of ActiveRecord's attributes as theirs getters and setters are not defined as methods.

```
module B
  def create_say_hello_if_not_exists
    puts respond_to?(:say_hello)
    define_method :say_hello do
      puts 'hello'
    end unless respond_to?(:say_hello)
  end
end

class A
  def say_hello
    puts 'hi'
  end
  puts respond_to?(:say_hello, true)
  extend B
  create_say_hello_if_not_exists
end

A.new.say_hello
```

The expected result is `hi`, but ruby prints `hello`. Why?

Maybe related to [Confused about "respond_to?" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893977/confused-about-respond-to-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
module B
  def create_say_hello_if_not_exists
    puts method_defined?(:say_hello)
    define_method :say_hello do
      puts 'hello'
    end unless method_defined?(:say_hello)
  end
end

class A
  def say_hello
    puts 'hi'
  end
  puts method_defined?( :say_hello )
  extend B
  create_say_hello_if_not_exists
end

A.new.say_hello
```

Comment: wow! what is the difference between `respond_to?` and `method_defined?`?

Comment: got it, the method is defined on the instance so `A.new.respond_to?` works. Thanks @kuriouscoder

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `respond_to?(:say_hello)` is returning `false` is due to the fact `class A` has `say_hello` as instance method and since you are extending `class B` the `create_say_hello_if_not_exists` is declared as class method and it does not find `say_hello`.

Changing the code to the following would do the trick. I'm declaring `say_hello` in `class A` as class method and am calling it in a static manner.

```
module B
  def create_say_hello_if_not_exists
    puts respond_to?(:say_hello)
    define_method :say_hello do
      puts 'hello'
    end unless respond_to?(:say_hello)
  end
end

class A
  def self.say_hello
    puts 'hi'
  end
  extend B
  create_say_hello_if_not_exists
end

A.say_hello
```